# Android: Show one row (text and Image) from database at a time and click on next button for next row

Tags: android, textview

What is the best way to show title and Image from the database? I just want to show one data row/record at a time and click on next button to show next data row/record. I am not able to figure out which view controls are best? I have seen tons of examples related to listview.

id | title | Image

1  Spring     image1.blob
2  summer     image2.blob
3  winter     image3.blob

logcat

```
06-07 04:33:06.213: E/Trace(950): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-07 04:33:08.041: D/Insert:(950): Inserting ..
06-07 04:33:08.150: D/AndroidRuntime(950): Shutting down VM
06-07 04:33:08.150: W/dalvikvm(950): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqlitedemoactivity/com.example.sqlitedemoactivity.SQLiteDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.example.sqlitedemoactivity.SQLiteDemoActivity.onCreate(SQLiteDemoActivity.java:37)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-07 04:33:08.171: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  ... 11 more
06-07 04:33:15.283: I/Process(950): Sending signal. PID: 950 SIG: 9
```

My code

```
private void setNewData(int position){
        textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getContact(position) ;
        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName();
            // Writing Contacts to log
            Log.d("Name: ", log); 
            textview1.setText(cn.getName());

        }
    }
```

button click code

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //increment the counter (which is keeps track of what position we are displaying.
                    counter = counter+1;
                    //call method to update the view with the next items position
                    setNewData(counter);
                }

            });
```

Comment: Are you only displaying 1 record at all time? If so, you may want to have a look at view pager.

Comment: I am using different record all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load all the items from your database into an array. Then use some simple code to keep track
of what item you are currently displaying. When the button is clicked, update the views
with the next items text/image. Heres some example code (which won't compile, but gives you an idea)

```
public class Thing{
    public String imageURL;
    public String text;
}

private List<Thing> myThings;
private int counter=0;
private Button nextButton;

nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            //increment the counter (which is keeps track of what position we are displaying.
            counter = counter+1;
            //call method to update the view with the next items position
            setNewData(counter);
        }
    });


 private void setNewData(int position){
    /*
     * Get the data from the list of the new position
     */
    String image = myThings.get(position).imageURL;
    String text = myThings.get(position).text;
    myTextView.setText(text);
    myImageView.loadImage(image);
}
```

Comment: {
   button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     //increment the counter (which is keeps track of what position we are displaying.
     counter = counter+1;
     //call method to update the view with the next items position
     setNewData(counter);
    }

   });
  }//